# Is there some way to share files with ssh cloud terminal?

Tags: file, ssh, terminal, cloud, sharing

I recently hosted my discord bot on an ssh terminal from google cloud, but to access my code, I need to delete the file, delete the de session, import the new file and start a new session... I can do with that but I cannot access my database anymore except if I download it, change it, delete the old one and upload it again... Is there some way to share files between the google cloud ssh terminal and my Linux storage so they both change when I edit only one?
Thanks

Comment: What is your database?

You should consider connecting to the database from your local machine  (with appropriate IP restrictions). Also, use the same database in local. However, I wouldn't recommend this for production data.

Comment: Actually my database is just a really long JSON file that contains all the users of the bot and some information about them, I would just like to access the file from my computer, and that when I edit it, the bot receives the edit to apply it. 
Do you have a suggestion about what I would rather use?

Comment: How about storing the file on storage like s3?

Comment: Every time you make the changes to the file, save it on s3 and use the s3 location in you service to download the latest data.

Comment: ok, thanks I'm gonna go check this out